# How to realize adding a new page in the asp.net mvc website without coding

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to realize adding a new page in the asp.net mvc website without coding.

Comment: if you are trying to avoid coding, I think you are in the wrong place???

Comment: I am trying to avoid tongue-in-cheek in the actual answers area, but there's a way. Just put <html>.....</html> in a .asp page and it will render just fine, though not dynamic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used to following controller and route mapping so that HTML developers can add new views before the real controller is built.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Simple",
    "{directory}/{file}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Simple", action = "Index", directory="home", file="index", id = "" }
);

public class SimpleController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index( string directory, string file, string id )
    {
        return View( string.Format("~/views/{0}/{1}.aspx", directory, file ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an html page (a file named with .htm ending) in a web editor (e.g. Microsoft FrontPage).

Copy that html file to an Asp.Net MVC website.

Voila: you have added a page to your Asp.Net MVC website without coding.

Answer (score 0):

so you are looking for a CMS, build with ASP.NET MVC?
then look at http://www.codeplex.com/oxite its a great example (but not a finished CMS!)